# How to "mirror" a plane onto itself

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, plane-geometry

I have a discrete set of points that describe a rectangular planar grid embedded in $R^3$.

I am also given one of the two normals to the plane and a graph specifying the connectivity of these points.

Assume that the winding order of the points in this grid is clockwise relative to the normal. I want to use a linear transformation to make the set of points have a counterclockwise winding order relative to the normal.

For example, if the grid spans the $(-1, -1)$ to $(1, 1)$ square centered at the origin and embedded in the $xy$ plane. Then for all points $p$ in the set one can do $p_x\rightarrow-p_x$ (i.e. mirror each point by the $x=0$ line). And this reflection will yield the opposite winding order.

I want to do this for any arbitrary plane, i.e. including those not containing the origin.

What rigid transformation do I use to achieve this?

Comment: If $P$ is the plane through a point $O$ and with unit normal vector $n$, the reflection in $P$ sends each point $x$ to$$R(x)=O+x-O-2[(x - O) \cdot n]n=x-2[(x - O) \cdot n]n.$$Is that the type of thing you mean?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I think, if I understand the above formula correctly that you are suggesting reflecting a point around the plane, i.e. "moving it to the other side" .

this is not quite what I am looking for. Assume $f$ is the function that solve my problem. 

The domain of $f$ is only the plane and so is its image. i.e $f$ is a permutation of the planar grid.

On input the planar grid (a graph with an embedded geometry) has a winding order for every polygon. 

The output is the same set of points in $R^3$ but each polygon has opposite winding order.

Does this clarify things?

Comment: I ought to have specified: The suggestion is not to reflect across the plane $P_0$ containing the polygon, but to pick a suitable plane $P$ containing the normal of $P_0$. <> In the case of a polygon in the $(x,y)$-plane, we might pick the $(y, z)$-plane (so $p_x \to -p_x$ as in your example).

Comment: This does change the winding order but depending on which $P_0$ plane you pick you might not end up with the same set of points as you had at the beginning, for example, cine there are infinitely many planes that satisfy the properties you specified, think about what most of them will do to the $xy$ example. In many cases the reflected points will occupy different positions than the input grid.

Comment: Right: If the polygon has no axis of reflection symmetry it's not possible to reverse the orientations of the edges by a reflection. (We _can_ always manually reverse the orientations of edges, just not by a spatial reflection.)

Comment: In this case we are working with a square grid, which has 2 axes of symmetry. So I guess that's the only way. I was hoping for a more elegant mechanism than brute force finding an axis of symmetry but I guess it cannot be done.

Comment: If it helps, workable axes of symmetry include the coordinate axes of the rectangular grid; that is, reflect in either plane containing a chosen point and parallel to a grid axis and the plane normal. (If the grid is square, the "diagonals" also "work.")